# Direct Music Player audio to Caller

Tags: calls, music, music-player

Assume you have a call. I would like to play a piece of one song to the caller at one point of discussion, while keeping your voice too in the discussion. 
I am using Android 6.0 CyanogenMod with Samsung Galaxy S4.

**Edited:** According to Media Playback's docs, the standard Android system does not allow the feature. 
However, I am interested in how this restriction works. 
If the feature works in non-rooted CyanogenMod, then it is not a restriction. 
Also, I am not sure if Media Playback's manual applies to the whole system.

How can you direct Music Player's output into the ongoing discussion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You cannot**

[Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) developer documentation says (emphasis added)

> You can play back the audio data only to the standard output device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth headset. **You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during a call**

**Edit**

In response to your edited question:

- I am not aware of Cyanogenmod permitting this- searching in their source code may give a clue
- To enable this, I presumed would require programming, so searched Stack Overflow and found this [Why it is not possible to play an audio file on a voice call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602114/why-it-is-not-possible-to-play-an-audio-file-on-a-voice-call-in-android). This gives a couple of reasons, in answers as to why it is not possible - **[security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27918838/5585644) and [prioritization of audio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27981383/5585644)**
- It also suggests ways of  achieving which are in programmers domain