# How to play speakers sound in microphone

Tags: audio

My question is simple but i haven't really found answers via google : How to use the sound played via speakers as microphone input ? (like Stereo Mix in Windows : for example, when you decide to put "Stereo Mix" for Microphone Device on Skype)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by asking this? Is this what you're looking to do: [Direct Music Player audio to Caller](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/136107)?

Comment: I'm not trying to do jokes, just to put some music on my answering machine when people want to let a vocal message after a missed call. To put music on answering machine is not free. It's also for general knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3.5mm male to male between your computer audio output and your phones headphone jack and then download an app that turns your headphone jack into a mic input. Can definitely be done on Android not sure about IOS