# Samsung Galaxy S6 - Want to talk on phone and listen to music at the same time - is this possible?

Tags: music, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 smartphone.

I want to talk on the phone and listen to music at the same time - is this possible? Is there a native app on the phone or another app that allows this?  I find it cuts the audio and video when I go away from the app producing audio and video typically, or when a phone call comes in.

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct Music Player audio to Caller](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136107/direct-music-player-audio-to-caller)